# Php script to redirect to m3u8 with proper sessionid

Tags: php

I am so sorry if this is the wrong section. I need some help. I have a few questions actually. I recently bought an iptv subscription with a provider. I am only able to play the channels on Android, I want to play it on kodi. However, I found out the method they use to encrypt the channels and what not. There's an encrypted page that is accessed using my login credentials and within that page(I think it's a json file), there's a session id. The session id goes in the m3u8 link as such: http://website.com/index.m3u8?sessionid=

How would I create a script that would load the json file,get the session id and connect it to the URL so that it plays? The session id expires every 15 minutes. I assume I would use php but I have no idea how to code. I am able to understand a tiny bit of code however. Also, the link with a proper session I'd doesn't play in kodi but it does in chrome.on Android. I assume that this is a user-agent issue? I have set the URL as such in kodi(http://website.com/index.m3u8|User-Agent=) with the proper useragebt but it doesn't work. I assume that they blocked the usage of user agent. Thanks a lot, and I am sorry if this is the wrong section.